# Pgfplots piecewise function wrong plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why the plot is wrong? The exponential function is positive so it must not goes below the 0 line

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture} [ declare function={
            func(\x)= (\x <= -1) * (0)   +
            and(\x > -1, \x < 1) * (exp(1/(\x*\x-1))) +
            (\x >=1) * (0);}]
            \begin{axis}[domain=-3:3]
                \addplot [blue,smooth] {func(x)};
            \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry thanks for tips

Comment: That is because of `smooth` ...

Comment: Unrelated: When using PGFPlots, you need to set the `compat` level - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `smooth` option tries to draw the function smooth in `x=-1` and `x=1` even when your defined function is not smooth. Try increasing the number of samples instead like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [ declare function={
func(\x)= (\x <= -1) * (0)   +
and(\x > -1, \x < 1) * (exp(1/(\x*\x-1))) +
(\x >=1) * (0);}]
\begin{axis}[domain=-3:3]
    \addplot [blue, samples=500] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with hump curve]